# how to remove login field when user login and display user's name?

Tags: java, authentication, passwords

I have one college management web application in which i have sign-in field for student and faculty on top of each page but i want to show that when user sign-in in web application then sign-in field must be disappear and in place of sigh-in field user's name must be display in all page. please suggest me.

Comment: [Take a tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and after that try to post [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

you may use header file which you include in every jsp page. and check if the user Or faculty is logged in then show label as value of their username or else show link like `sign in`